# How I can show the breakpoints dots per-line on file-buffer using gud-gdb?

Tags: gud, gdb

Using `gdb` defined by package `gdb-mi.el` I got the breakpoints red dots after click on line with mouse or defining on `gdb` buffer. However, using a alternative wrapper for `gdb` present on the stantard packages of emacs `gud-gdb` defined on `gdb.el,` I cannot. This is possible? Only shows on my buffer the current point of execution (white arrow).

Example: calling gdb from `M-x gud-gdb RET`
[image: Calling gdb from <code>gud-gdb</code>]

Example: calling gdb from `M-x gdb RET` (desired behavior about breakpoints)
[image]

Someone can ask whyI just not use the `gdb`and forgot about `gud-gdb` and the answer is because I can't. On my Windows machine I receive a lot bugs and crash using it. The bugs is mainly because the bad Cygwin support about handling stdin far I know. Just doesn't works debugging via `gdb` programs whose read something from stdin, he injects the string `-interpreter-exec console` as I described recently on [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44994122/using-emacs-with-gdb-windows-cygwin-injects-to-stdin-interpreter-exec-on-begi). So I need use `gud-gdb`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We could probably work through the specific problems, but I have a feeling this is not going to be of much overall value. Perhaps try using realgud instead and then let's work out the issues there. As best as I can tell, gud-gdb is really not maintained anymore and probably for good reason. gdb-mi is I think more recently maintained, but apparently has problems too. And you will find realgud has problems too, but at least I am willing to work through some of them.

Comment: I undestand. But using gdb-mi will not work since the problem is about Cygwin on an ancient bug, so I think using gdb-mi on windows is pretty hopeless. The definitive "solution" is just to forget about gdb-mi on windows and use gud-gdb (and ignore the lack of features provided by gdb-mi). By another hand, on Linux I can user whatever I wish.

Comment: Yes, you've said that gdb-mi will not work on Cygwin. And improving gud-gdb doesn't look like a possible avenue either which is probably why everyone has ignoring you. So you can keep carping on about your problem or try something *different*.

Comment: Indeed. But this feature is not a big deal too. I'm using `gud-gdb` since I opened this question and works fine, the mouse feature is something forgetful. I only opened this question to see if someone passed by the same problem. Since not, actually I until forgot about it and just remembered it after you comment here. I'll test realgud later, thanks for the tip.